# Windows 11: Cannot delete ubuntu from efi folder "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, efi

My dual boot installation ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS did not work. So I deleted the partition volume I was going to use for the installation. However, I am stuck with the ubuntu still as an option in my bootloader. I tried the methods of `bcdedit /enum firmware`, `bcdedit /delete <id>`. However when I restart ubuntu still shows up as an option as a firmware application. I also went into `diskpart`, mounted my fat32 parition and dir into the efi folder. Everytime I tried to `rmdir \S ubuntu` bootloader from the folder, I get `The system cannot find the file specified.` I am on Windows 11 Home version 21h2 os build 22000.493

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SusrL.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9kyb.png)
[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKBN1.png)

Comment: Have you tried a regular filesystem check (`chkdsk /f`) on that volume?

Comment: I have. Results were: `Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.` Also did `chkdsk /v` and directory and files were shown too.

Comment: Boot to WinRE, mount the EFI partition via `DiskPart`, then try deleting `EFI\ubuntu`

Comment: I tried booting into WInRe and deleting. Still received `The system cannot find the file specified.` Ubuntu is still on my computer as I can still boot into in but can't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark as I'm a noob myself.

Have you tried steps 5-8 as listed in [this microsoft help thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/uninstalling-ubuntu-operating-system-in-dual/2999ebfd-4b86-45fe-aa6b-96c969803bb6)? It's an old thread but the menu still exists.

> 5. Click on start button, Type in the search box “Run”
> 6. In the Run box Type “MSconfig” to remove the boot entry.
> 7. Click on the "Boot" tab in the window that appears.
> 8. Highlight "Ubuntu" by clicking on it with your mouse. Next, select the "Delete" option located underneath the list of operating systems.
>    This will remove "Ubuntu" from the list of options you are presented
>    with when your computer starts.

Comment: Yes, there is no ubuntu listed in my msconfig boot tab.

Answer (score 0):

#### Background

I was trying to delete `EFI/ubuntu` from System volume from Windows 11.

I followed normal process of opening cmd as system admin and reached till the point where I mounted the disk and got inside `EFI` dir to find `ubuntu` dir.

When I ran `rd ubuntu /s` it showed me an error saying directory is not empty, also got a notification in windows saying the file `/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` is corrupt and not readable.

### Solution

Ran `chkdsk /f` to fix corrupted files and chose `y` couple of times. It attempted to fix the file and failed to do it. Then it automatically deleted the file :p Problem solved!

Then I attempted to delete the `ubuntu` dir again `rd ubuntu /s` & it worked!

Restarted into Bios and checked boot loader, I could only see Windows (no ubuntu entry) in the list.

> ps: Before everything, I tried to delete `grubx64.efi` manually with `del` command but it could not do it.

Hope this helps!